# Pick which swap partition to use for Suspend to Disk

Tags: linux, hibernate, swap, suspend

Is there anyway in Linux to pick which swap partition to use for Suspend to Disk? I have a setup with 2 swap partitions, one on an SSD and one on a HDD. I want the swap partition on the HDD to be used for all normal swapping purposes. When I need to hibernate I want the hibernate data to be stored on the SSD.

I know how to use priority to control which partition is used for the normal swapping, how do I choose for suspend to disk? I guess this question also begs the question of which partition would be used for hibernate by default in the first place? I would guess the one with the highest priority?

Comment: is there a reason for you to use a swap partition on HDD? Most people will use the SSD one anyway

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc honestly not a very good one, in the meantime I ended up just setting it up on the ssd. (The overall problem is due to me using LUKS on LVM so the swap for resume needs to be on the disk decrypted by `cryptsetup`. I guess I just having lingering fears from the days when the sort of writes done to swap would kill a ssd. I do have `vm.swapiness = 1` its honestly just fear mongering :)

Comment: **lvm on luks** not the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) `resume=` for that.

You probably might want to take a peek at [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/interface.txt) about power management in general as well, though you'll probably do just fine without knowing all the details.

Comment: I will need to test this out. I of course knew about the `resume=` kernel parameter however I thought that only specified to the kernel **where to look** not also where to store the file. It'd be great if it also becomes where it's stored